# Scala: Pattern of collection / item

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to have a design pattern with `trait` or `class`:

```
class Collection(input: F[A]) { 
   def combineWith(other: Collection): Collection

   def combineWith(other: A): Collection
}
```

With `F` being `Set`, `List` , `Seq` etc...

And `A` being of type `Item`:

```
class Item(....) {
   def wrap: Collection[Item]
}
```

I tried but I get into a loop of having the item needing the types of the collection and the collection needing the type of the item and it gets out of hand haha.

I am sure there must be a pattern to be able to reuse but I cannot find it.

I am starting to use `ScalaZ` so if there is something I can use there, that would be great.

The end goal is to have a pair `Item <-> Collection` where the collection can only accept item of the right type and where the item can only be in this collection. And be able to go back and forth with `wrap` and be able to add collections:

- `Item +: Collection`
- `Item |+| Item`
- `Collection :+ Item`
- `Collection ++ Collection`

All of those operation should return the `Collection`. I have several in my project and I don't want to copy paste the same code everywhere.

**Edit: Example:**

Imagine `case class Human(body: Body)` and `class Body(limbs: List[Limbs])`

You can have methods for `body` which would iterate through `limbs` and cases where you want to deal with body as a whole.

What would be the best way to represent that ?

**Edit:**

Isn't this pattern a Monad or one of those Functor , etc... ?

If I do something like:

```
 class MyCollection(item: Item*) {
     def map(f: Item => Item): MyCollection

     def flatMap(f: Item => MyCollection): MyCollection

     def filter(p: Item => Boolean): MyCollection
 }
```

Would that works?

Something like: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xn304lefRbO7vjwhopgE8g

no ?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with ordinary (non-wrapped) collections, and *why* are you trying to do what you are trying to do? Looks like an XY problem to me.

Comment: I need enhanced methods related to what the `Item` type is.

Comment: First of all, I will strongly suggest you to stay away from the idea of thinking about things like `Item ++ Collection` or `Collection ++ Item`. That does not give you enough extra convenience to warrant the encroachment of well understood and conventional meaning of `++`. If you have any other practical and "non anti-pattern" enrichment needs for `Item`, please say and we can help. But not for this one, its looking too much of an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: If you just need "enhanced methods" then have you considered using an `implicit class` to add the functionality to the existing collection types? The general pattern is to have functions that you `map` on to collections to create new collections, rather than putting the functions in the collections themselves. The functions on a collection should relate to the collection itself, not the contents.

Comment: I feel like there are cases where that make sense. Imagine `case class Human(body: Body)` and `class Body(limbs: List[Limbs])` you can have methods for `body` which would iterate through `limbs` and cases where you want to deal with `body` as a single entity. What would be the best way to represent that ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSinghI edited my question with different operator and added an example.

Comment: `The end goal is to have a pair Item <-> Collection where the collection can only accept item of the right type and where the item can only be in this collection.` Still unclear what it's supposed to be good for. If you are trying to implement linear logic of some sort, then Scala's type system is not  a good fit for that. Otherwise, I don't understand why *"the item can only be in this collection"* is a meaningful goal. If you want just the `|+|`-operation, then just take `Monoid`. *"How to model human body"* would be a way too broad and too vague question.

Comment: [2] I don't see how artificially introducing weird circular mutually recursive dependencies for no obvious reason would make *anything* clearer, under any circumstances.

Comment: I added a scastie with code sample

Comment: Ok, so, what positive effect does it achieve that `case class Body(parts: List[BodyPart])` doesn't?

Comment: I don't know, this is my question haha.